# PHP make transparent png with text

Tags: php, image, png

I´m running this code which creates a transparent png of 640x1136 and ads a white box with black text in the top left corner.

When running the code png is created but this is returned as output

```
?PNG

IHDR?z??
        IDATx???1 ?Om
??>g???IEND?B`?
```

Do any one happen to know what this is?

At the same time, could anyone think of a shorter way?

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(640, 1136);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $color);
imagepng($im);
imagesavealpha($im, true); // important to keep the png's transparency 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$width = 640; // the width of the image
$height = 1136; // the heighst of the image
$font_size = 20; // font size
$box_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
// Set the offset x and y for the text position
$offset_x = 0;
$offset_y = 20;
$dims = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $text);
$text_width = $dims[4] - $dims[6] + $offset_x;
$text_height = $dims[3] - $dims[5] + $offset_y;
// Add text background
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $text_width, $text_height, $box_color);
// Add text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $text_color, $font,$text);
imagepng($im, $img, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the correct `header` with your data:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Or, if you're trying from a console, and you wish to direct the output to a PNG file you should either run it as `php <yourscript>.php > filename.png` or change `imagepng($im);` to `imagepng($im, 'filename.png');` What your script is currently doing is outputting the PNG to the output, and you see the raw PNG data.

Comment: Make sure you place the `header()` call at the top of your script.

Comment: Problem still persists

Comment: Are you running the script through a Web browser and a Web server or from the console?

Comment: That explains it. If you wish to direct the output to a PNG file you should either run it as `php <yourscript>.php > filename.png` or change `imagepng($im);` to `imagepng($im, 'filename.png');` What your script is currently doing is outputting the PNG to the output, and you see the raw PNG data.